# Automate proxy web browser connection with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

why don't you change my ip to the one put there,

IE starts, it connects to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), but the IP does not change with the one in the code

I want to set a proxy in the browser, which of course can be changed if needed and I don't understand why it's not ok

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY_HOST = "2.56.119.93"
PROXY_PORT = "5074"
PROXY_USER = "hwgucghh"
PROXY_PASS = "gcdf3wi14xua"

# create a new ChromeOptions object
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# add the proxy to the ChromeOptions object
proxy = f"{PROXY_USER}:{PROXY_PASS}@{PROXY_HOST}:{PROXY_PORT}"
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % proxy)

# create a new Chrome driver with the ChromeOptions object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# load a website
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# do something
print(driver.title)

# quit the driver
driver.quit()
```